# Link which selects one of the buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to select one of those 3 buttons with a URL link? I open the link and one of the buttons is already clicked.

Do I require to add a specific script?

```html
<button id="uno" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1')">
  one
</button>

<button id="dos" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '2')">
  two
</button>

<button id="tres" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '3')">
  three
</button>
```

Comment: So how is a url supposed to relate to a button??

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Are you sure you want to emit a `button click` or do you just want to invoke `openCity` with some arguments? If so, in your JavaScript, you can write:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  openCity(3);
}

function openCity(buttonNum) {
  console.log(buttonNum); // '3'
}
```

If you want to emit a button click, you can try:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');
  const firstButton = Array.from(buttons)[0];
  firstButton.click();
}
```

Comment: `openCity` needs to take an event as its first parameter to be compatible with the buttons' onclick events